# CodeIgniter 4 Vendor not detected when calling

Tags: codeigniter, visual-studio-code, codeigniter-4

[image: image show that it cannot find it]

I don't know what I've been doing, maybe I accidentally change the CI4 configuration.

So, I'm installing "hermawan/codeigniter4-datatables" with Composer and it successfully installed.
Then, when i call it inside Controller, it seems like ci4 can't find it. I'm using VS-Code, so when I type `use Hermawan\DataTables\DataTable`, I cannot ctrl + left click.

When I use another project (past), its normal. But in this project is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you've imported the library or autoloaded the library.

```
use \Hermawan\DataTables\DataTable;
```

as well this need `php-sql-parser`

---

If above all done n still running errors, use

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: well, i did the composer dump then the error still remain. After that i despair, then close the VSCode. The error is disappear when i open the project again, so maybe the problem is the VSCode, but thanks for your help.